# Refresh materialized view does not work using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, materialized-views

I am trying to refresh materialized view using JDBC connection, but the data does not seem to refresh. Below is the query.

```
private static final String REFRESH_X_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_SQL =
            "refresh materialized view X.X_overview_mv;";
.
.
.

try (Connection connection = postgreSQLConnectionFactory.getXConnection();
            PreparedStatement refreshMaterializedViewStmt =
                connection.prepareStatement(REFRESH_X_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_SQL)) {
            refreshMaterializedViewStmt.execute();
```

Is it possible to achieve this using JDBC?

Comment: what is the error that you see? this should work, if it works from psql prompt. Do you see this statement logged in postgres logs?

Comment: I have tried same today using Cockroach using the Postgres jdbc driver  and I could not make it work.
Database comes back "with cannot refresh materialised view when there is an explicit transaction".
I then proceeded to debug the JDBC drive down to the protocol level and found that with my query the driver was definitely NOT sending a begin tran to the database, I could see those lines being skipped.
So at present I believe there is something about the jsbc impl that makes this operation is impossible rfrom jdbc using the pg driver and cockroach.